# C# loading assembly at runtime which require higher .net version?

Tags: c#, .net

I have code targeting .Net 2.0 which uses Assembly.Load() to execute the entrypoint of user-provided executable in order to analyze it. What will happen if this user provided executable require higher version of .Net then available on the system?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I don't have test VM setup for this and hoped to get the answer in order to  consider how feasible targeting 2.0 would be. Furthermore I can't find this question asked on stackoverflow so I think it's not inappropriate.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: throw an exception that can be cached and message displayed, instead of running until some method call is made that willl crush it, because of the JIT nature of the CLR. Is there something funny about my question I really fail to see?